# C# (Discord.Net) Checking a message for words in file

Tags: c#, filter, discord, discord.net

im trying to do a badword filter for an discord bot.

My Code does not give me some errors, but it also doesnt work. Maybe someone could help me?

Here is me Code.

```
            private async Task BadWordsWarn(SocketMessage message)
    {
        string[] badWords = File.ReadAllLines("bad_words.txt");

        if (badWords.Any(word => message.Content.IndexOf(word, 0, message.Content.Length, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        {
            var m = (RestUserMessage)await message.Channel.GetMessageAsync(message.Id);
            await m.DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you have a single badword, that you want to filter out of a message? Have you ever debugged, what you did? Do you even get into the await message.DeleteAsync() call?

Comment: I got a textfile with a bunch of words

Comment: You want to do this in a loop. Loop over the array and use the check inside it

Comment: Could you tell me an example maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe change it to

```
if (badWords.Any(message.Content.Contains))
    await message.DeleteAsync();
```

That'll scan through all your bad words and stop if it finds one.

Also consider using a case insensitive comparator like StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase

```
if (badWords.Any(word=>message.Content.Contains(word, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    await message.DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: Yes.  It does :)  Try adding "using System.Linq;" at the top of your file

Comment: I'm using System.Linq. The problem is, that messge.Content.Contains didn't accept the second argument. Did you develope Discord.Net bots also? If yes, is it right to declare it like _client.MessageReceived += BadWordsWarn ?

Comment: Ahh, perhaps an older version of the framework.  You can change it to: word=>message.Content.IndexOf(word, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0 … I think .IndexOf with the comparer object has been around a while including in old frameworks.  Could do the ugly .ToLower() hack on the source and word strings, in a pinch, though, instead of using a stringcomparer. :) … (I'm afraid I don't know Discord.Net though, sorry)

Comment: I have to give an int startIndex and an int count like that:
word => message.Content.IndexOf(word, 0, 0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
Is the count the count of words in my list?

Comment: If you're going to do it with all those parameters, the second "0" should be "message.Content.Length", to examine the whole string. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224423(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I edited my code, but it still doesnt work. Could you tell me if its right or not? You can see the new code in my thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static Task BadWordsWarn(SocketMessage msg)
    {
        string[] badWords = File.ReadAllLines(@"bad_words.txt");
        foreach(string badWord in badWords)
        {
            if (msg.Content.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Contains(badWord.Replace(" ", "")))
            {
                msg.DeleteAsync();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for me. In my list a have a new line for every words, sometime there are 2 words in 1 line, "hello world" for example. I tried it with .Split(' '); and also with .Split('\n') but it does not work.

Comment: @MendaxM. I've updated the code, now it can filter out multiple-word and concordant(I don't know that I translated the previous word correctly, so for example "bad word" = "badword") bad words.

Comment: Thats just delete all mesages.